# How transpile via IDE ES6 to ES5 (and React-JSX) with WebStorm on Win10 with Babel6?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, webstorm, executable, babel-6

A lot of sources explain that for this you need to

- create a "File Watcher"-Job in the WebStorm-Settings (Tools)
- define a "Scope" in WebStorm for the files you want to process
- define a .babelrc file for configuration. Babel will use this automatically so you save some params in the call

`{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]
}`

- `npm install --save-dev` the corresponding packages together with the babel-cli package.

BUT... how can I run the babel-Command on Windows when babel-cli module just delivers a "babel.js" file in its bin-folder? However Windows can only execute .exe, .bat or .cmd-files.

I tried to wrap the call in a cmd-script containing `babel %*` as I found a solution in one web article, but this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to fill the File Watcher form in a way to have the call of the node executable as **Program** and add the call for babel.js as first of the **Arguments**

- Program: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
- Arguments: `$ProjectFileDir$/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --source-maps --out-dir src/test/js`
- Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`
- Output paths to refresh: `$ProjectFileDir$\src\test\js`

This makes the babel.js callable for the File Watcher.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/